# Playing a video triggered by a PIR

Tags: video

How would I go about using a raspberry pi to play a video, every time the user is "in front of" the screen (detected by a PIR sensor).

Ideally, the screen would be blank, until the sensor is triggered, then a fullscreen video will play with sound, before returning to black.

Comment: Write some python code to detect a signal on a GPIO pin from the PIR sensor, then use the omxplayer-wrapper to play the video. Use the pygame library to clear a black screen.

Comment: @CoderMike I would make the comment an answer. I would upvote it.

Comment: Halloween project?

Comment: Yes, Chad! Will report back how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write some python code to detect a signal on a GPIO pin from the PIR sensor, then use the omxplayer-wrapper to play the video. Use the pygame library to clear a black screen.

Comment: omxplayer-wrapper was the part I was missing thank you!